# React Native setInterval function for multiple function with different duration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two functions in React Native Component, in that one should refresh every 10s and another one should refresh every 1s. I have implemented **`setInterval()`** function for refreshing on `componentDidMount()` and **`clearInterval()`** on `componentWillUnmount()`, but am facing trouble it takes only one function which has the lowest duration. But am achieving result if set duration of both function same duration.

Here is the example

```js
...
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      btLevel: 0,
      btState: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBtLevels();
    this.getBtState();
    this.batLS2();
    this.batLS10();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(() => { this.batLSS(); this.batLS10(); });
  }
  getBtLevels = () => {
    fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
      this.setState({btLevel: res.level}),
    );
  };
   getBtLevelArcs = () => {
      fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
      this.setState({btLevelArc: res.level}),
    );
   };

  getBtState = () => {
     fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
      this.setState({BtState: res.state}),
    );
  };
  
   batLS10 = () => {
     setInterval(() => {
      this.getBtLevelArcs();
  
    }, 10000);
   };
  batLS2 = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
       this.getBtLevels();
       this.getBtState();
    }, 1000);
  };

...
```

On the above Code  `this.getBtLevels(); this.getBtState();` fetch value every 1 seconds and `this.getBtLevelArcs();` fetch value every 10 secounds. In this `this.getBtLevels(); this.getBtLevelArcs();` functions get same value. But one should refresh every 1 second and another one every 10 seconds. Here am getting is 1s *setInterval* function `this.batLS2()` is refresh whole component.

How can I achieve this one should refresh value 1s and another 10s.

here is the Original Version code. [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@fussionweb/batlel)

Comment: `clearInterval` works by being passed the reference returned from `setInterval`, i.e. `this.timerId = setInterval(...` and `clearInterval(this.timerId)`.

Comment: @DrewReese  I appreciated that, but can you brief with example.

Comment: Combining @shubham Answer its work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`clearInterval` works by being passed the reference returned from `setInterval`, i.e. `this.timerId = setInterval(...` and `clearInterval(this.timerId)`.

What I suspect is occurring is you edited you code and ran, which set an interval callback (but didn't clear it), and then edited and re-ran your code, which sets another interval callback (again, not cleared), etc... You basically aren't cleaning up the interval callbacks when the component unmounts (like a page refresh).

## Solution

Add a timer variable for each interval timer

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  ...

  this.timer1 = null;
  this.timer2 = null;
}
```

Clear each interval on dismount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.timer1)
  clearInterval(this.timer2)
}
```

Save the timer ref

```
batLS10 = () => {
  this.timer2 = setInterval(() => {
    this.getBtLevelArcs();
  }, 10000);
};

batLS2 = () => {
  this.timer1 = setInterval(() => {
    this.getBtLevels();
    this.getBtState();
  }, 1000);
};
```

[image: Edit nostalgic-snow-iqx3u]

Comment: Still persist the same issue, might be the wrong implement on my side, I have updated code in Expo.

Comment: @Fussionweb I commented out all the fetches and extraneous functions in my sandbox to distill it down to as simple an example as possible. If you can recreate/reproduce your issue in a *running* codesandbox please update your question with link to it and include any new details you discover.

Comment: @Fussionweb In that expo snack I added console logs to the interval callbacks and in the Web build they appear to fire at correct intervals, 1s and 10s each. I was unable to get the code to run on simulated iOS or Android though. https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/batlel

Comment: Yes! We can't run Android and iOS because react-native relink, But that arc refreshes each 10s it's not working for the web version, let me run-in Real simulator.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood by the example and statement is you want `getBtLevels` and `getBtState` to be called after every 1 sec and `getBtLevelArcs` after every 10 seconds.
But what happens is when `getBtState` and `getBtLevels` invoke, their `setState` updates the whole component, which is not acceptable in your case.

Ideally this should not be a problem, because all the three functions have different states. `btLevel`, `btLevelArc` and `btState`. Updating one state should not impact the other one. But that totally depends upon your UI logic.

If that is still a problem: what you can do. You can split your component into two components. First one will hold the UI related to `getBtLevels` and `getBtState` and second component will contain UI related to `getBtLevelArcs`. This is required because setState will re-render the whole component.

Code will be something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    ...
    //some common handlers for SubApp1 and SubApp2
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <SubApp1 />
                <SubApp2 />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }    





class SubApp1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            btLevel: 0,
            btState: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getBtLevels();
        this.getBtState();
        this.batLS2();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(() => { this.batLSS(); });
    }
    getBtLevels = () => {
        fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
            this.setState({ btLevel: res.level }),
        );
    };


    getBtState = () => {
        fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
            this.setState({ BtState: res.state }),
        );
    };

    batLS2 = () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getBtLevels();
            this.getBtState();
        }, 1000);
    }
      ...
      ...


class SubApp2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            btLevelArc: 'some default value'
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.batLS10();
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(() => { this.batLS10(); });
    }
    getBtLevels = () => {
        fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
            this.setState({ btLevel: res.level }),
        );
    };

    getBtState = () => {
        fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
            this.setState({ BtState: res.state }),
        );
    };


    getBtLevelArcs = () => {
        fetch(apiUrl).then((res) =>
            this.setState({ btLevelArc: res.level }),
        );
    };
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: Combine First and second answer I have achieved  the result

Comment: If that worked for you, kindly accept the answer :) That motivates us to write more :)